# Advanced conditional to show entries where a field is empty

Tags: ee2, conditionals, syntax

I'm trying to show a list of all entries in a certain channel, in a certain category. I've got that much. In that, I'm trying to list all entries where a certain field is empty. I'm not getting the results I'm expecting, and I'm having trouble finding how to list a field value as being empty.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="spc-content" category="5" orderby="title"}
{if content_featureimage ==""}<li>{title}</li>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}</ul>
```

Here's the output I'm getting, [on this page](http://www.sparklecrackcentral.com/such/blog/). (Yes, the formatting is nonexistent. This list is essentially "housekeeping" - so that I can more easily figure out which entries I need to go back and fix.) I'm expecting at least four times the number of entries I'm getting in that list, so it's possible that my if-statement syntax is not the world's best. But...what should the correct syntax be, if I want to see a list of all entries that don't have anything in the content_featureimage field?

I'm running EE 2.5.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you should use parameter `search:content_featureimage="IS_EMPTY"` within channel entry tag.

Comment: This got me more listings, but there still seem to be some that I'd expect to see, that aren't showing up. H'm. (But this worked! Thanks!) EDIT: I changed it to a numbered list, and if I didn't specify a limit, the list topped out at 100 items. I added the parameter limit="1000" and I got over 300 entries - which is about what I expected to get. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

or you can try `{if '{content_featureimage}' == ''}<li>{title}</li>{/if}`

Comment: I gave this solution a try, and got some PHP errors: Severity: User Warning, Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable (filename libraries/Functions.php, like 2843); Severity: Warning, Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by [[string removed for security reasons]] (filename: core/Common.php, like 412)